# Quasi-separated rigid-analytic space without a formal model?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, formal-schemes

Well, my question is slightly embarrassing. When learning rigid geometry (mostly from Bosch's book) I realized that I don't know the answer to the following basic question.

> **Question.** Is there an example of a quasi-separated rigid-analytic space which does not admit a formal model?

For completeness, let me include the setup:

- $K$ is a non-Archimedean field (complete with respect to a nontrivial valuation),
- $\mathbf{Rig}_K$ is the category of rigid-analytic spaces over $K$, and $\mathbf{Rig}^{\rm qs}_K$ is the subcategory of quasi-separated rigid-analytic spaces,
- $\mathcal{O}$ is the valuation ring of $K$, given the $t$-adic topology for any $t$ with $0<|t|<1$,
- $\mathbf{FSch}_\mathcal{O}$ is the category of formal schemes locally of finite presentation over $\operatorname{Spf}\mathcal{O}$, i.e. locally of the form $\operatorname{Spf} \mathcal{O}\langle X_1, \ldots, X_n\rangle/(f_1, \ldots, f_s)$ where $\mathcal{O}\langle X_1, \ldots, X_n\rangle$ is the $t$-adic completion of $\mathcal{O}[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$,
- $\mathfrak{X}\mapsto \mathfrak{X}_{\rm rig}\colon \mathbf{FSch}_\mathcal{O} \to \mathbf{Rig}_K^{\rm qs}$ is the rigid generic fiber functor, i.e. it sends $\operatorname{Spf} A$ to $\operatorname{Sp} A[1/t]$ and Zariski open covers to admissible covers (the result is always quasi-separated).

The question asks for an example of an object not in the essential image of
this functor.

What is known:

- Every quasi-compact and quasi-separated rigid-analytic space admits a formal model (Raynaud, Bosch--Luetkebohmert)
- More generally, every quasi-paracompact and quasi-separated rigid-analytic space admits a formal model (Chapter 8 of Bosch's book). Quasi-paracompactness means that there exists an admissible cover $X=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha$ by quasi-compact opens such that every quasi-compact open $V\subseteq X$ intersects only finitely many of the $U_\alpha$.

Some observations:

- It is a bit tricky to construct non-quasi-paracompact examples of quasi-separated rigid spaces, but it can be done. There exist integral schemes locally of finite type over a field $k$ which are not of finite type, and therefore not quasi-paracompact. (There was a nice MO thread on this, I will link it later.) If $Y$ is such a scheme over $k$, we take $\mathcal{O}=k[\![t]\!]$, $\mathfrak{X}$ the formal completion of $Y\otimes_k \mathcal{O}$, and $X = \mathfrak{X}_{\rm rig}$. Then I think $X$ is not quasi-paracompact. But, you see, it has a formal model by construction...
- The notion of "tautness" from the theory of adic spaces might play a role. (An adic space is *taut* if the closure of every quasi-compact open is quasi-compact.) It seems quite close to quasi-paracompactness, so extra credit if you can find an example which is taut.

Comment: Hi Piotr! About you first observation, I think the space $X$ you get can still be quasi-paracompact. In the standard example of a surface blown-up at a point, then at a point on the exceptional divisor, and so on, you get a space that is a countable union of spaces of finite type. This is enough to ensure quasi-paracompactness if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I agree that it is difficult to construct complicated examples of rigid spaces without relying on formal models (even Drinfeld's upper half-plane). In Berkovich spaces or adic spaces, you have more tools available. For instance, in the Berkovich setting, take a valued field $k$ with uncountable residue field, consider the closed unit disk of dimension 2 and its open subset obtained by removing the Gauss point. The latter is the standard example of a non-paracompact space (still taut I believe). I don't know if it belongs to your essential image though.

Comment: @JérômePoineau Thanks for those comments! In your first comment, note that the scheme is integral, so every non-empty open contains the generic point. Therefore you cannot cover it by quasi-compact opens such that each one intersects only finitely many others, and the scheme is not quasi-paracompact. Similarly, the closure of a non-empty qc open is the whole thing, so it is not "taut". It is plausible (though I didn't check) that if $X$ is a rigid space admitting a formal model where this strange variety appears in the special fiber, then $X$ is not quasi-paracompact nor taut either.

Comment: You are right of course. For some reason, in my mind, the construction was on the generic fiber, which gives something different.